getting nested entities are not supported on Spring Reactive Flux
I have two users in my app a user that is used to login and another that is related linked to the first user using a foreign key ( oneToOne relationship ). I'm trying to create an api that allows for registration using Spring Boot ( the code uses JHipster ). When I try to create both users on the same Mono I get the error displayed on the top : Getting nested entities are not supported on Mono
    @Transactional
public Mono<User> registerUser(AdminUserDTO userDTO, String password, String phoneNumber) {
    KariaUser kariaUser = new KariaUser();
    return userRepository
        .findOneByLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase())
        .flatMap(existingUser -> {
            if (!existingUser.isActivated()) {
                return userRepository.delete(existingUser);
            } else {
                return Mono.error(new UsernameAlreadyUsedException());
            }
        })
        .then(userRepository.findOneByEmailIgnoreCase(userDTO.getEmail()))
        .flatMap(existingUser -> {
            if (!existingUser.isActivated()) {
                return userRepository.delete(existingUser);
            } else {
                return Mono.error(new EmailAlreadyUsedException());
            }
        })
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .then(
            Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                User newUser = new User();
                String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
                newUser.setLogin(userDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase());
                // new user gets initially a generated password
                newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
                newUser.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
                newUser.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
                if (userDTO.getEmail() != null) {
                    newUser.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail().toLowerCase());
                }
                newUser.setImageUrl(userDTO.getImageUrl());
                newUser.setLangKey(userDTO.getLangKey());
                // new user is not active
                newUser.setActivated(false);
                kariaUser.setUser(newUser);
                kariaUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                kariaUser.setRole(RoleEnum.RENTEE);
                kariaUser.setFirstName(newUser.getFirstName());
                kariaUser.setLastName(newUser.getLastName());
                kariaUser.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
                kariaUser.setAddressLine1("");
                kariaUser.setGender(Gender.OTHER);
                kariaUser.setCity("NaN");
                // new user gets registration key
                newUser.setActivationKey(RandomUtil.generateActivationKey());
                return newUser;
            })
        )
        .flatMap(newUser -> {
            Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
            return authorityRepository
                .findById(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                .map(authorities::add)
                .thenReturn(newUser)
                .doOnNext(user -> user.setAuthorities(authorities))
                .flatMap(this::saveUser)
                .doOnNext(user ->{
                    log.debug("Created Information for User: {}", user);
                    kariaUser.setUser(user);
                    kariaUserService.save(kariaUser).subscribe();
                });
        });
}

I also have a OneToOne Relationship between the two entities:
Here is the code sample that references it:
public class KariaUser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
private User user;

The error happens on the subscription:
kariaUserService.save(kariaUser).subscribe();

